# Как написать слэш в имени файла

Tags: python, парсер

Такой вопрос. Нужно указать в название файла идентичное название ссылки, к приимеру это
« http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/2284783.stm ». Как мне указать слэши? Как я понял можно что-то сделать с кодировкой, но я так и не понял как это сделать. Имя файла должно выглядить вот таким образом
« http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/2284783.txt ». Расширение файла может быть и « .doc » или любого дргого текстового редактора

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import html2text

class Pars ():
 #'http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/2284783.stm'
 def __init__(self, url):
     self.text = url
     #print ('//////Text///////',self.text)
     self.s = urllib.request.urlopen(self.text).read()
     #https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/faq.html
     #https://amdm.ru/akkordi/maks_korzh/102669/v_temnote/
     soup = BeautifulSoup (self.s, features='html.parser')
     for script in soup(['script', 'style']):
         script.extract()
         self.html_text = str(html2text.HTML2Text().handle(soup.text))
         #print (html_text)
         print (self.html_text)

class Write (Pars):
 #print ('text')

 def WriteFile (self):
     self.text = str(self.text)
     #print ('test', self.text)
     self.html_text = str(self.html_text)
     #print ('SELF.HTML_TEXT', self.html_text)
     name_file_1 = self.text.replace(':', '+')
     name_file_1 = name_file_1.replace ('/', '_')
     name_file_2 = os.path.splitext (name_file_1)[0] + '.doc'
     print ('Name you file', '\n', name_file_2)
     file = open (name_file_2, 'w')
     print ('And path', '\n', os.path.abspath (name_file_2))
     file.write (str(self.html_text))
     #print ('test')

url = input()
Job_Pars = Pars(url)
Job_Write = Write(url)
Job_Write.WriteFile()
```

Comment: Никак. В имени файла не может быть слешей

Comment: Вот, смотрите, тут как-то это сделали и вроде даже объяснили как, но я не понимаю

Comment: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/14384375

Comment: Там не слеши, а, скорее всего, символ деления. В любом случае лучше расскажите что за задачу вы решаете и зачем вам понадобились слеши?

Comment: Я делаю парсинг сайтов (любой один сайт, который я ввожу с клавиатуры), далее я записываю полученные данные в файл. После чего мне необходимо дать название файлу. К примеру: если ссылкой было «http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/2284783.stm», то имя файла должно быть «http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/2284783.txt. Как видите поменялось лишь расширение, для того чтобы файл можно было открыть в редакторе.

Comment: В любом случае использовать слеши невозможно

Comment: В таких случаях обычно просто заменяют слеши на подчёркивания, например. Но если хочется поэстетствовать, то можно на деление заменить. А расширение лучше не заменять, а добавлять

Comment: Деление вы имеете ввиду «\»?

Comment: И ещё один вопрос. Как мне производить переос строки если при парсинге встречается ссылка? Сейчас попробую добавить код

Comment: @Decya а в чем проблема создать такой же физический путь из папок например?
/2/hi/health/2284783.txt - (папка "2" -> "hi" -> "healt" -> файл "2284783.txt")

Comment: Хм. Ну тоже неплохой вариант, хотя он и не подходит под задачу. Но спасибо